# umbraco site as a subfolder of azure website

Tags: azure, umbraco, azure-web-app-service

I would like to install Umbraco as a subfolder (not subdomain) of my site on Azure.
Is this possible to do, and if so, how do I go about making sure all the settings are correct? I have looked for documentation on this and couldn't find any.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your Umbraco site as a virtual directory within Azure. I haven't done this myself but I know it should be possible. You will have to ensure that the virtual directory web.config overrides/resets everything that may conflict from your parent application.

The best way to achieve this is create exactly the same set up locally. So within your local IIS (not IIS Express) create your parent application and create Umbraco as a virtual directory.

There iss an article here which describes the process for getting your virtual directory hosted on Azure: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/09/22/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website.aspx

In a nutshell, it's similar to the process in IIS but via Azure Management Portal, e.g. defining the directory to make a virtual directory and choosing whether it should be marked as an application (which it should).